# Integration test with embedded jetty not working

Tags: maven, jetty, embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I want to make test end to end with angular so I try to run a embedded jetty.

First, I have created this conf in pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.26</version>
  <configuration>
    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
    <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
    <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
    <connectors>
      <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        <port>29439</port>
        <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
      </connector>
    </connectors>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>start-jetty</id>
      <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <daemon>true</daemon>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>stop-jetty</id>
      <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>stop</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

but the test are blocked with karma e2e waiting a response from the jetty. If I try to browse localhost:29439 there is nothing.

As It's very hard to debug, I tried to upgrade to a new jetty version but it was the road to hell :(

For exemple, the following conf keeps giving me NoClassDefFound error:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>7.6.14.v20131031</version>
  <configuration>
    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
    <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
    <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
    <webApp>
      <contextPath>/</contextPath>
    </webApp>
    <connectors>
      <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        <port>29439</port>
        <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
      </connector>
    </connectors>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-jsp</artifactId>
      <version>7.6.14.v20131031</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>start-jetty</id>
      <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>start</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <daemon>true</daemon>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>stop-jetty</id>
      <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>stop</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Any solution or tips will help, either with debugging the 1st version or make the 2nd version works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working pom.xml for you.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>webapp-2.5</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>webapp-2.5 Maven Webapp</name>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jetty-version>7.6.14.v20131031</jetty-version>
    <slf4j-version>1.7.5</slf4j-version>
    <logback-version>1.0.13</logback-version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>webapp-2.5</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty-version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
          <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
          <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
          <webApp>
            <contextPath>/</contextPath>
          </webApp>
          <connectors>
            <connector
              implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
              <port>28080</port>
              <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
            </connector>
          </connectors>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback-version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty-version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>start-jetty</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
              <daemon>true</daemon>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>stop-jetty</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

This will do the integration phase start/stop, with logging configured, as well as the supporting `$ mvn jetty:run` on a Servlet 2.5 webapp.

**Working Example**

A working example webapp has been uploaded to github.

https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-maven-plugin-examples

See the webapp-2.5 sub-project

To build the war

```
$ mvn clean install
```

To run the jetty server using your jetty-maven-plugin configuration

```
$ mvn jetty:run
```

Goto your browser and hit any of the following URLs to see it working.

- `http://localhost:28080/` - simple html response from `src/main/webapp/index.html`
- `http://localhost:28080/time` - simple servlet response from `org.eclipse.demo.TimeServlet`
- `http://localhost:28080/flarnsworth` - an invalid reference, so this will trigger the `<error-page>` handling and return a response from `org.eclipse.jetty.demo.ErrorServlet`
- `http://localhost:28080/dump.jsp` - a jsp response from `src/main/webapp/dump.jsp`

Comment: Ahhhh ... My E2E tests is blocked at :
karma start /Users/ygrenzinger/Xebia/SFR/sibo360/src/test/resources/karma.e2e.conf --single-run

If I try to go to localhost 29439 there is no response.
And when I kill the maven run with Ctrl-C, I see this error:
[WARNING] FAILED jsp: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspApplicationContextImpl
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspApplicationContextImpl

Comment: The JSP error you are seeing is not from that example pom.  (almost) same pom is in example project just uploaded for you.